# How to download files from a download link?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, discord

Hey i want to get the files downloaded from https://files.transtutors.com/cdn/usersolution/1404331_1_637266356378408650_o.docx saved to my replit directory with the file name `doc.zip`
can u help me plz i am using `discord.py`

i am expecting to get the files from the link: https://files.transtutors.com/cdn/usersolution/1404331_1_637266356378408650_o.docx get downloaded with the file name : `doc.zip` in replit directory

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried so far. Additionally, your question contains the same text twice.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to discord.py but anyways

You can use [`urllib.request.urlopen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen)

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen # import the method

with urlopen("http://example.com/") as download: # open the url
    file_content = download.read().decode() # save and decode the download content

with open("doc.zip", "a") as file: # append to the existing zip, else create a new one
    file.write(file_content) # write the content into the file
```

Check this question as well: [How to download a file over HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-to-download-a-file-over-http)